# Django ORM: How to return ONE value from subquery when it is impossible to use GROUP BY (in django it is values("field to group by")

Tags: subquery, django-orm, aggregation

Given the following code:

#models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Comment(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="comments")
```

#then create some data

```
from y_subquery_outeref.models import *

# Create post
post1 = Post.objects.create(text="post1")   # --- POST1
post2 = Post.objects.create(text="post2")   # --- POST2

# Create comments to POST1 ----
comment1_post1 = Comment.objects.create(text="Comment1_post1", post=post1)  # id - 1
comment2_post1 = Comment.objects.create(text="Comment2_post1", post=post1)  # id - 2
comment3_post1 = Comment.objects.create(text="Comment3_post1", post=post1)  # id - 3

# Create comments to POST2 ----
comment1_post2 = Comment.objects.create(text="Comment1_post1", post=post2)  # id - 4 !!! VERY IMPORTANT
```

#views.py

```
comment_count = Comment.objects.filter(
    Q(
        Q(post_id=OuterRef("pk")) |
        Q(pk=4)  # With this condition it is not possible to group by "post_id" anymore!
    )
).values("???").annotate(
    comment_count=Count("id")
).values("comment_count")
```

Using this query, **I want subquery to somehow return the total count number of all comments (COUNT(*)) that either have post_id from outer query or pk=4**.
However, now **I can't simply use GROUP BY** **post_id** and count all comments ids, like I would do without this condition.

```
Q(pk=4)
```

How can achieve such behaviour that the subquery will return total number of comments that satisfy both conditions?

The desired output should be like this:

**post1 has 4 comments count**

**post2 has 1 comments count**

The raw SQL solution will be like this:

```
SELECT 
    post.*,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comment 
        WHERE 
            (post.id = comment.post_id)
            OR comment.id = 4
    )
FROM post
```